# printf-style string formatter

Tags: javascript, strings, console, formatting

As part of a larger project I'm working on, I've made a function that aims to replicate, as best as I can, the placeholder part of the `console.log()` function usable in most browsers.

It replaces `%s`, `%d` , `%i` , `%f` and ,`%o`. It works by having 'unlimited' parameters (the replacements), looping through the parameters, checking for any placeholders and replacing them by index with the parameter given. The `switch` is for checking whether the passed parameter (replacement) is the correct type - if not, it will add `NaN`, just like the real console would.

My main questions are:

- Is my code readable?
- Are there any better ways to do any part of this?
- Can it be cleaned up anymore?

```
function replacePlaceholders(string) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1); //get all the extra arguments (exclude the original string)
    var counter = 0; //set a counter

    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { //loop through the extra arguments (should match the number of placeholders in the string)
        var match = /%s|%d|%i|%f|%o/.exec(string); //regex
        if (match) { //if match found
            var index = match.index; //store the index
            switch (match[0]) { //check whether the placeholder has a real value with the correct type
                case '%s': //for strings
                    string = (typeof args[counter] == 'string') ? string.substr(0, index) + args[counter] + string.substr(index + 2) : string.substr(0, index) + NaN + string.substr(index + 2);
                    break;
                case '%d': //for numbers....
                case '%i':
                case '%f':
                    string = (typeof args[counter] == 'number') ? string.substr(0, index) + args[counter] + string.substr(index + 2) : string.substr(0, index) + NaN + string.substr(index + 2);
                    break;
                case '%o': //for objects
                    string = (typeof args[counter] == 'object') ? string.substr(0, index) + args[counter] + string.substr(index + 2) : string.substr(0, index) + NaN + string.substr(index + 2);
                    break;
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return string;
}

console.log(replacePlaceholders("string %s %d %i %f %o", 'string', 1, 4, 5.5, {one: 1})); //test case
```

You can test this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shub01/kfehpeza/) - check the console for the returned string.

Comment: It seems to me that this function is a string format-er. After all, the "f" in `printf` stands for "format".

Comment: @SirPython 'string formatter' is the phrase I was looking for! Yes that's what the function is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I start: Thank you so much for making this code easily readable! Thank you from the bottom of my heart!

---

Second thing that I have noticed was the name. It's wrong! If it is a `sptrinf`-like function, give it the right name. `sprintf`! Done! No overly complicated boring names.

---

You have an argument called `string`. Please, don't do that. In fact, remove it's name! You know it is the first element.

You can do this:

```
var text = arguments[0];
for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
```

Done! But it won't be needed and you will see why.

---

You still didn't learn: Store the length in a local variable. **Always**! Like this:

```
for (var i = 1, length = args.length; i < length; i++) {
```

Accessing a property in an object (in this case, an array) is slower than accessing a loval variable. By setting the local variable with that slow property, we increase performance.

---

It is really a great idea to have literal regular expressions, but the whole code is quite... shady... Specially the useless validations!

You expect a string to be a real string so you can do something... But why? What about a number? What about an array? What around something else? Why can't I convert anything into a string? Every single object has the `.toString()` method.

And why that `NaN` there? What is it for? Is that to say it is `NaN`?

---

The `%o` is doing something somewhat somewhere that I don't get. By the [C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) specify that this is the octal representation.

---

And now, the questions:

- Why do you check if an argument is a `string` before converting it to string?
- Why do you check if an argument is og any type before converting?
- why don't you do **any** kind of validation?
- Why are you using `exec`?

I would **never** do it on this way. It's so frail and picky. It's so hard to change anything without breaking it. You have to deal with things you should, like breaking a string in 3 parts and replacing the middle part with something. That's a **bad** way to do a `.replace()`.

I would do like this:

```
function sprintf(){
    var toBase = function(value, base){
        //converts to the required bases
        return (parseInt(value, 10) || 0).toString(base);
    };
    var map = {
        s: function(value){
            return value.toString();
        },
        d: function(value){
            return toBase(value, 10);
        },
        i: function(value){
            return this.d(value);
        },
        b: function(value){
            //binary conversion
            return toBase(value, 2);
        },
        o: function(value){
            //octal conversion
            return toBase(value, 8);
        },
        x: function(value){
            //hexadecimal conversion
            return toBase(value, 16);
        },
        X: function(value){
            //HEXADECIMAL CONVERSION IN CAPITALS
            return toBase(value, 16).toUpperCase();
        },
        e: function(value){
            //scientific notation
            return (parseFloat(value, 10) || 0).toExponential();
        },
        E: function(value){
            return this.e(value, 10).toUpperCase();
        },
        f: function(value){
            //floating point
            return (parseFloat(value, 10) || '0.0').toString();
        }
    };

    //crude way to extract the keys
    var keys = '';
    for(var k in map)
    {
        keys += k;
    }
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice();

    return args.shift().toString().replace(new RegExp('%([' + keys + '])','g'),function(_, type){
        if(!args.length)
        {
            throw new Error('Too few elements');//appropriate type here?
        }

        return map[type](args.shift());

    });
}
```

Come on! It's so easy to understand! You can change it's functionality easily!

If you want, you can remove that loop to fetch the keys and use this literal regular expression: `/%([diobsxXeEf])/g`. Same thing, but faster and less flexible.

And this is a "good enough" clone of the `sprintf` function. It doesn't support padding, float-number size specifitation and others. But, it works for the bare minimum.

---

Outside the scope of this review, thanks to you, I finally have a function to write my [polyglot](/questions/tagged/polyglot) questions! Also, you may want to look at http://phpjs.org/functions/sprintf/ if you want a perfect clone of the `sprintf` function.

---

To reflect closely the desired implementation, one can change the `map` variable. I went a bit further and changed all unnecessary things. To be consistent with the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console) and the [Chrome console API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object), you can do this:

```
function sprintf(){
    var map = {
        s: function(value){
            return value.toString();
        },
        d: function(value){
            return (parseInt(value, 10) || 0).toString();
        },
        i: function(value){
            return this.d(value);
        }
        f: function(value){
            return (parseFloat(value, 10) || '0.0').toString();
        }
    };

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice();

    return args.shift().toString().replace(/%([difs])/g,function(_, type){
        if(!args.length)
        {
            throw new Error('Too few elements');
        }

        return map[type](args.shift());

    });
}
```

The `%o`, `%O` and `%c` specifiers are implemented internally and isn't possible to implement using this method. `%c` and `%C`work on elements, by creating a list in the console or a link to the element to show in the Element Inspector. The `%c` uses CSS styles to style the output in the console itself.

Comment: You've made some good points about the code, but there are quite a few where you don't explain *why*. For example, *why* should the length be stored in a variable in the loop? *Why* is the code shady? Please add some more of an explanation to your points where you do not have any explanation; while some may understand why, others may not.

Comment: (Continue from above). *Why* would you "**never**" do it on this way?

Comment: @SirPython What do you think now?

Comment: `sprintf` is much more advanced than `console.log()`; I guess there's no *problem* in replicating `sprintf`, but my target was to replicate the function of console.log... I don't do any conversions, because console.log() doesn't - if you go to your browser's console and type `console.log("test %f", ['test'])`, you get `test NaN` - the browser doesn't convert it for you... I use `exec` because it returns the index (I forgot to link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2295681/3541881 :/)... `%o` in the console refers to an object...

Comment: However, you have some good suggestions! Thank you and I will surely use some of them :) +1!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ The function I've made can be extremelly easily changed to represent those values. Remember that `%c` is used for CSS styles. I really though you were trying to replicate the `sprintf` functions. You can easily change the code to do what you want. I've implemented similar functionality on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets/256170. I will edit to refer to the desired implementation.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Nice - it seems my end product is basically the same as yours! I'm making a new `log` function that both logs to console and shows a small box on the page for easier use when debugging!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I hope to see the final result. Mine has a bunch of methods implemented. All of them help quite a lot.You should try canon's implementation and take a few bits from there. I took the idea to log uncaught errors from there, with explicit authorization from the author.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yeah I can see, but I don't want to look too much at your source code - you know... because it's hard to think of something else when you someone else's code and you end up copying it! But I'll definitely look at canon's error part! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It is really easy. You just have to do `window.addEventListener('error', function(e){ [code] });`. And thank you a lot for accepting the answer.